# Cannot pass parameter through activities in Android

Tags: android

I am new to android app development and I have the following problem when I pass a parameter through activities. In my app the user enters his email, username and password, clicks the submit button and then he goes to the next activity (NewProfile.class) where his username should be printed in a TextView. But when the user fills in all  fields correctly and the toast "Welcome to Allamoda" is shown, each field become red (this happens only when user enters something wrong) and then he returns to MainActivity.

Signup.class code:

```
package dmst.allamoda;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Signup extends ActionBarActivity{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    setupVariables();
}
private EditText email;
private EditText username;
private EditText password1;
private EditText password2;
public static String PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER = "";

public void signupControl(View view) {

    if ((email.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) && (username.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) && (password1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) &&
            (password2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) && (password1.getText().toString().equals(password2.getText().toString()))) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Welcome to AllaModa!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NewProfile.class);
        resultIntent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, username.getText().toString());
        setResult(NewProfile.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();

    } else {
        if (!(email.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " email!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (!(username.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " username!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (!(password1.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " password!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (!(password2.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " password!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (!(password1.getText().toString().equals(password2.getText().toString()))) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "passwords!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

        email.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5CCCC"));
        email.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B80000"));
        username.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5CCCC"));
        username.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B80000"));
        password1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5CCCC"));
        password1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B80000"));
        password2.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F5CCCC"));
        password2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#B80000"));
    }

private void setupVariables() {
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signupEmail);
    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signupUsername);
    password1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup1Password);
    password2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup2Password);
}
}
```

Comment: I am unclear what your expected and actual results are, can you please be more specific in your question?

Comment: I edited my question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Sorry, no still not clear to me. (1) Are you trying to start a NEW activity? or (2) Are you trying to return to MainActivity and wondering why each field becomes red?  For #1, see cybersam's answer below. For #2, we would need to see code in MainActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Signup` is not transitioning to the `NewProfile` activity. It is returning to the prior activity (presumably, `MainActivity`).

This is the problemmatic code:

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, NewProfile.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, username.getText().toString());
    setResult(NewProfile.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
```

Presumably, you want to do something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewProfile.class);
    intent.putExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER, username.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

[EDITED]

The `finish();` statement at the end should keep the `Signup` activity out of the history stack in more modern devices. However, some commenters to this answer (@AndrewBreen and @Cookster) indicate that doing so may not work on slower devices.

If you are worried about this, @Cookster's comment presents a possible solution to this that avoids the call to `finish()`:

> The pattern I use to avoid this is to have the activity that opened
>   the login activity act in a routing capacity in onActivityResult i.e.
>   it checks login state, if not valid then opens login activity,
>   otherwise does actions that required auth state etc.

Comment: Weird, I tried to edit this and remove the 'finish()' but it did something else. Anyways, best to not call finish() when starting new activities. This could result in Signup.class exiting before NewProfile appears. The user might see a flash of whatever is on the back stack between transitions.

Comment: @Cookster This is very a common coding pattern when you want to remove the current activity (like one for logging in) from the history stack while transitioning to another activity. Please provide evidence that it can cause the problems you listed, and, ideally, show a better solution.

Comment: I worked but now the TextView in NewProfile.class which takes the value of the parameter is not displayed.
Here is my method in NewProfile.class
     `@Override
     public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
switch(requestCode) {
case (1) : {
if (resultCode == NewProfile.RESULT_OK) {
String newText = data.getStringExtra(PUBLIC_STATIC_STRING_IDENTIFIER);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username);
textView.setTextSize(40);
textView.setText(newText);
setContentView(textView);
}
break;
}
}
}`

Comment: `onActivityResult()` is only called when an activity you launched *returns* to your activity. In this case, `NewProfile` did not launch another activity -- it is the one being launched (by `Signup`). You probably need to move the logic in the innermost block into [onCreate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)). You should study the documentation for the Activity lifecycle, or refer to a good book an Android.

Comment: I am a beginner so I didn't understand what I have to do

Comment: @cybersam I have seen this occur on weaker hardware where two activity transitions is too much at one time. The pattern I use to avoid this is to have the activity that opened the login activity act in a routing capacity in `onActivityResult` i.e. it checks login state, if not valid then opens login activity, otherwise does actions that required auth state etc.

Comment: @cybersam - In this scenario, Activity A launches Activity B, then Activity B finishes and launches Activity C. In this scenario you create a condition where Activity A may come into view before Activity C is shown. The typical flow would be A->B->C with smooth transitions. But by explicitly calling finish() you are potentially breaking that transition of leaving Activity B in the foreground while Activity C transitions into view. And as user above said, slower systems and slower hardware typically exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Very interesting. @AndrewBreen: I suppose that kind of coding (in the activity that opened the login activity) would probably need to be there anyway. However, wouldn't there be more of a tendency to see some flickering (especially in slower devices)?

Answer (score 0):

try this on activity a

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
i.putExtra("SomeKEY",YourData);
```

On activity B in the oncreate method

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras !=null)
if(extras !=null) {String value = extras.getString("KEY");}
```